# Issue to load images using NSURLRequest on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I am creating an ios application, where i am passing five images in my carousel at run time using AFNetworking. The problem is that, the very first time when i am downloading images from server so i cant able to download all the images at once and as a response sometimes i am getting 3 or 4 if need to download five images from server. Each image size is  approx 100 KB.

Here is my code :

```
for (int i=0; i<[slideShowArray count]; i++) {

    SlideShow *pro = [[SlideShow alloc] init];
    pro = [slideShowArray objectAtIndex:i];// slideShowArray is an array of image urls
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pro.imageUrl];

    UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                     NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                     imageview.image = responseObject;
                     [slideshow addImage:imageview.image]; // here i am adding multiple image on my carousel

                      if (!isLoadSlideshow) {
                       isLoadSlideshow = TRUE;
                        [slideshow start]; // this is to start my carousel to slide images after some delay
                     }

                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
               }];
    [requestOperation start];

}
```

As i have added page control as well as moving images, here i am getting five images from server. As an output, it is displaying 5 dots in page control but image slider is not reaching to the last. How can i solve this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you download all the images at once? Why not just use `AFImageView` and get that to download the images on demand?

Comment: Also, a few coding notes: **1)** Use fast enumeration, so in this circumstance you can change the first line of code to `for (SlideShow *pro in slideShowArray) {`. **2)** Don't use `TRUE`, you should be using `YES`.

Comment: @GuyKogusThanks for reply, the reason is once user will come to this screen that time i need to slide all the respective images paging wise after downloading all images.

Comment: Your code to download the images seems to be fine. I think the issue is with your slide show UI component and we'd need to see the code for that.

Comment: Okey, is it possible to add any placeholder image here? so i can display at least default avatar image..

Comment: Of course, just set an image before starting the operation to load it remotely.